# Getting out a single value from a sql database (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm trying to get a single value from my table in a database. They are all given a unique id when stored. Here is the code I use to put the in:

```
With SqlDataSource1
   .InsertParameters("page").DefaultValue = ViewState("TrueURL")
   If My.User.IsAuthenticated Then
      .InsertParameters("sender").DefaultValue = My.User.Name
   Else
      .InsertParameters("sender").DefaultValue = Request.UserHostAddress.ToString
   End If

   .InsertParameters("details").DefaultValue = PrepareText(TextBox2.Text)
   .InsertParameters("date").DefaultValue = Now()
   .Insert()
End With
```

That was so you could get an idea of what I was looking for, I'm not looking for sql statements, I don't know how to use them.

Just keep in mind, this is all vb.net/asp.net.

Thanks!

--EDIT--

I think I found something useful but I can't find how to use it.  The Select function.  It returns something and accepts parameters like the insert one I mentioned above... any ideas?

Comment: @mark Thanks for the edit, I thought it did it for me.  I guess I was wrong =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant extract it without first running an SQL query to extract it.

If you've got this far, read a little further in the MS help pages about how to run the select querys, this is where you would put your SQL statements.

Comment: The sqldatasource loads in the table.  I just need to get out a single entry via vb.net.  I don't know what you mean by the MS Help pages, I've been learning mostly from trial and error.  (Thanks anyways)

Comment: Trial and error is both frustrating and fun.

Yes, but at the same time if you had 1,000,000 records in your table, do you really want it to load all that for the sake of one line?
Currently, thats what you're asking of it. Select statements can refine what it is going off and asking of the database to return just the relevant lines.

Comment: I'm unsure on how to implement a system such as that.  How would I do a select statement via vb.net?  It, in the end, needs to return so I can access my "timeposted" thing in my table.